# Python 3.5: Guessing the cube root game is returning None as an output

Tags: python, python-3.5

I've looked up other answers regarding the issue but I'm having a hard time implementing the solution in my program (still pretty new to Python). Here's what I have so far:

```
# Purpose: 'guess' randomly selects a number between 0 and 100 (including those
# numbers) and calculate the cube of that number. It also prompts the user to 
# guess the cube root of the cubed number, displaying 'Correct!' if correct, and
# asking the user if they would like to try again if incorrect.

def guess():
    import random
    rand = random.randint (0, 100)
    cubed = rand*rand*rand

    # Forming the input question
    string = "What is the cube root of"
    cubed = str(cubed)
    qmark = "?"
    question = print(string, cubed + qmark)

    user = int(input(question))
    while (user == rand):
        print ("\nCorrect!")
        user = input("\n\tWould you like to try again?").lower()


    if (user != rand):
        print ("\tIncorrect!, the cube root of", cubed, "is", rand)
```

And this is supposed to be what the output looks like:

```
guess()

What is the cube root of 64000? 56
            Incorrect, the cube root of 64000 is 40

            Would you like to try again? y

What is the cube root of 216? 6
        Correct!

        Would you like to try again? n

Goodbye
```

Comment: Your function doesn't contain any `return` statements, so of course it returns `None`. Why is that a problem?

Comment: What output do you achieve with your current code?

Comment: What is the cube root of 'cubed'?

None

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really good beginning attempt at a function! 2 things to fix:

1) The question variable shouldn't have a print in it. Putting a variable in input() will print it for you. This would be better:

```
question = string+" "+cubed+qmark
```

2) The bottom section isn't quite right. Maybe you want something like this? The last line calls the whole function again - this is called "recursion".

```
user = int(input(question))
if (user == rand):
    print ("\nCorrect!")
elif (user != rand):
    print ("\tIncorrect!, the cube root of", cubed, "is", rand)
user = input("\n\tWould you like to try again?").lower()
if user == "y":
    guess()
```

Put together, here is the final Code:

```
# Purpose: 'guess' randomly selects a number between 0 and 100 (including those
# numbers) and calculate the cube of that number. It also prompts the user to 
# guess the cube root of the cubed number, displaying 'Correct!' if correct, and
# asking the user if they would like to try again if incorrect.

def guess():
    import random
    rand = random.randint (0, 100)
    cubed = rand*rand*rand

    # Forming the input question
    string = "What is the cube root of"
    cubed = str(cubed)
    qmark = "?"
    question = string+" "+cubed+qmark #################### Remove print here. Input will do it for you.

    user = int(input(question))
    if (user == rand):
        print ("\nCorrect!")
    elif (user != rand):
        print ("\tIncorrect!, the cube root of", cubed, "is", rand)
    user = input("\n\tWould you like to try again?").lower()
    if user == "y":
        guess()
    else:
        print("Goodbye")

guess()
```

I have only started programming recently myself, and this is my first time I have helped someone!

Edit: following a suggestion in the comments, here is a way to do it without using recursion, by putting everything in a "While True Loop", also known as a forever loop:

```
def guess():
    while True:
        import random
        rand = random.randint (0, 100)
        cubed = rand*rand*rand

        # Forming the input question
        string = "What is the cube root of"
        cubed = str(cubed)
        qmark = "?"
        question = string+" "+cubed+qmark #################### Remove print here. Input will do it for you.

        user = int(input(question))
        if (user == rand):
            print ("\nCorrect!")
        elif (user != rand):
            print ("\tIncorrect!, the cube root of", cubed, "is", rand)
        user = input("\n\tWould you like to try again?").lower()
        if user != "y":
            print("Goodbye")
            break

guess()
```

Comment: Don't use recursion like that. It's messy and can cause crashes if it recurses too deep. Use a loop, that's what they're for.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I've just posted an alternative non-recursion way of doing it using a forever loop.

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
def guess():
    import random
    rand = random.randint (0, 100)
    cubed = rand*rand*rand

    # Forming the input question
    question = "What is the cube root of {cubed} ?".format(cubed=cubed)

    user = int(input(question))
    if user == rand:
        print ("\nCorrect!")

    else:
        print ("\tIncorrect!, the cube root of", cubed, "is", rand)

choice = 'y'
while choice == 'y':
  guess()
  choice = input("Would you like to play again ?").lower()
else:
  print("Goodbye")
```

You were storing return value of `print` function (which is `None`) in `question` and then passing `question` to `input` function which was printing it